# How to connect API with vue.js

Tags: vue.js, web, vuejs2, frontend, backend

I have a small problem, don't understand how to connect the frontend and backend so email and password are verified from the database. I have programmed this in Vue.js for Login and Register page. And now I need to connect it with API so data is verified from the database and it is hard quite hard for me to understand it because I am learning Vue now.

```
<template>
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-content>
      <v-container class="fill-height" fluid>
        <v-row align="center" justify="center">
          <v-col cols="12" sm="8" md="8">
            <v-card class="elevation-12">
              <v-window v-model="step">
                <v-window-item :value="1">
                  <v-row>
                    <v-col cols="12" md="8">
                      <v-card-text class="mt-12">
                        <div>
                        <section>
                            <iframe width="600" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ebuUqH4ZVUQ" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                        </section>
                    </div>
                        <h1
                          class="text-center display-2 teal--text text--accent-3"
                        >Sign in to Tetris</h1>
                        
                        <h4 class="text-center mt-4">Ensure your email for registration</h4>
                        <v-form>
                          <v-text-field
                            label="Email"
                            name="Email"
                            prepend-icon="email"
                            type="text"
                            color="teal accent-3"
                          />

                          <v-text-field
                            id="password"
                            label="Password"
                            name="password"
                            prepend-icon="lock"
                            type="password"
                            color="teal accent-3"
                          />
                        </v-form>
                      </v-card-text>
                      <div class="text-center mt-3">
                        <v-btn rounded color="teal accent-3" dark>SIGN IN</v-btn>
                      </div>
                    </v-col>
                    <v-col cols="12" md="4" class="teal accent-3">
                      <v-card-text class="white--text mt-12">
                        <h1 class="text-center display-1">Hello, Friend!</h1>
                        <h5
                          class="text-center"
                        >Enter your personal details and start journay with us</h5>
                      </v-card-text>
                      <div class="text-center">
                        <v-btn rounded outlined dark @click="step++">SIGN UP</v-btn>
                      </div>
                    </v-col>
                  </v-row>
                </v-window-item>
                <v-window-item :value="2">
                  <v-row class="fill-height">
                    <v-col cols="12" md="4" class="teal accent-3">
                      <v-card-text class="white--text mt-12">
                        <h1 class="text-center display-1">Welcome Back!</h1>
                        <h5
                          class="text-center"
                        >To Keep connected with us please login with your personnel info</h5>
                      </v-card-text>
                      <div class="text-center">
                        <v-btn rounded outlined dark @click="step--">Sign in</v-btn>
                      </div>
                    </v-col>

                    <v-col cols="12" md="8">
                      <v-card-text class="mt-12">
                        <h1 class="text-center display-2 teal--text text--accent-3">Create Account</h1>
                        
                        <h4 class="text-center mt-4">Ensure your email for registration</h4>
                        <v-form>
                          <v-text-field
                            label="Name"
                            name="Name"
                            prepend-icon="person"
                            type="text"
                            color="teal accent-3"
                          />
                          <v-text-field
                            label="Email"
                            name="Email"
                            prepend-icon="email"
                            type="text"
                            color="teal accent-3"
                          />

                          <v-text-field
                            id="password"
                            label="Password"
                            name="password"
                            prepend-icon="lock"
                            type="password"
                            color="teal accent-3"
                          />
                        </v-form>
                      </v-card-text>
                      <div class="text-center mt-n5">
                        <v-btn rounded color="teal accent-3" dark>SIGN UP</v-btn>
                      </div>
                    </v-col>
                  </v-row>
                </v-window-item>
              </v-window>
            </v-card>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
      </v-container>
    </v-content>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
    step: 1
  }),
  props: {
    source: String
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: What backend are you using?

Comment: Are you using axios library?

If not check that.

Comment: @PawelKam All backend is written in PHP.

Comment: @Dusan And yes I did import Axios.

Comment: In that case you'll find many online tutorials to get you started, for example this one using PHP's Laravel https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vd1YwbHrY1Q&list=PLfdtiltiRHWF1jqLcNO_2jWJXj9RuSDvY

Comment: Thanks Pawel that will help me too.

Comment: Just, install axios, configure and use it

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to know what is client, server and how they work via the HTTP protocol in the case you mentioned.
Then, search the documentation, you could find the usage code.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)